# How to use mySQL count using joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having following database schema, I want to fetch name of all categories with no of quotes related to that category . The query that i wrote giving me one row only can u please tell me the resource efficient query.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code (just to have a starting point)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SC.Name, Count(*) AS Quotes
FROM status_categories AS SC
INNER JOIN status_quotes AS SQ ON SC._id = SQ._category_id
GROUP BY SC.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT status_categories.NAME, COUNT(status_quotes.category_id)
FROM status_categories JOIN status_quotes ON status_categories._id = status_quotes.category_id
GROUP BY status_categories._id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT     `c`.`name`, COUNT(*) AS `Number of quotes`
FROM       `status_categories` AS `c`
INNER JOIN `status_quotes` AS `q`
    ON     `q`.`category_id` = `c`.`_id`
GROUP BY   `c`.`_id`;
```

***EDIT***

Feel free to leave out the ` character. But that is the *safe* way of doing it, even though it looks a bit nasty.